# Change Legend Box Outline Chart.js 2

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to remove the stroke color from the legend generated by ChartJS, but I can't quite seem to understand what [the documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration) is telling me.

My current code looks like this:

```
legend: {
  position: 'bottom',
    labels: {
      generateLabels: function() {
        return {
          strokeStyle: "black",
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Though I have tried this:

```
generateLabels: {
  strokeStyle: "black",
}
```

I'm setting the stroke style to "black" to see if I'm having any effect, but I'm not even sure if that's what I'm supposed to be doing. I would think I could set it to none.

**Edit**

Here is the code for my full object:

```js
    var ctx = $('#chart');
    var data = {
        labels: ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [22,19,17,15,10,9,8],
            backgroundColor: [
                '#df4344',
                '#fc9627',
                '#fcd949',
                '#d4d81e',
                '#6dc7ba',
                '#24a38e',
                '#263a7e',
                '#5050b2',
                '#4f7ec1',
                '#96afe2',
            ],
            borderColor: ["black"],
            borderWidth: 2
        }]
     };

    var wheel = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "doughnut",
      data: data,
      options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        tooltips: false,
        cutoutPercentage: 60,
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

But now that I run it here, it seems to be working. So I'm not sure what's wrong anymore.

Comment: And I can't figure out what that error is in the code snippet either, if anybody wants to fix it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To remove the stroke from legend, you need to set **`borderWidth`** property to **`0`** for your dataset, like so ...

```
datasets: [{
   borderWidth: 0,
   ...
}]
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Statistics',
         data: [3, 1, 2, 5, 4],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.1)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.8)',
         borderWidth: 0 //<-- set this
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: I have a doughnut chart that I've already removed the border width on, and it isn't reflecting in the legend. When I change the border width, it affects the spaces between the segments, but not the legend.

Comment: does this not also affect the chart itself? What if I want my chart data to have a border but not the legend?

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 I found that `pointBorderWidth` worked also, but this affects the points instead. A bit weird weird, but should be of use if your graph isn't using points!